# XMPP/jabber client help

Tags: google-app-engine, chat, xmpp

I want to develop a chat application with floowing features

1. 1)user A visits website clinks on
   chat .
2. 2)Website picks another user B who
   is single(who is not paired) and
   pairs him with A.
3. 3)Now A and B can chat till they
   want.

Now here neight A or B are registered member of website.Neight they ave any accouunt.

Can i develop such things using jabber/XMPP on appengine ??If yes how??please provide some pointers so that i can start off.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507620/chat-application-on-appengine -- why not just edit that question?

Comment: @jason: That question was abt chat website.This one is specifically for jabber client.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of app is absolutely possible on App Engine, using XMPP, but you won't be able to have them talk directly to eachother, only to your app.  You can then "bounce" messages from User A to User B via your bot.

1.) A user visits site, enters their jabber ID (or you could have them log in). You would need to store this JID in the datastore

2.) Another user visits the site, enters JID, and you pick some random existing "single" JID.

3.) Mark both of the JIDs as "connected" and send each a message to start chatting.

4.) At this point, your app can receive messages from the first user, and send them to the second user, and vice versa.  This will also help reduce spam and privacy issues, since users won't need to give their actual JID to a stranger.

As for pointers, [the App Engine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/) are a good place to start, specifically the section on XMPP ([Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/) / [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/)).

Comment: @jason:Thanks for replying.But my client(A and B) dont have a jabber id.Can my server create jabber id  on the fly  whenever a clint needs?

Comment: A Jabber ID is what the XMPP service sends to. Your users will need to have a Jabber ID in order to talk to your service.  Your server can't create a JID for a user, because the user needs to have one to talk to the server in the first place.

Comment: @jason:I want to implement a site similar to omegle.com.Can u please tell me if its possible to develop using jabber/xmpp

Comment: You will be able to connect random users together who have Jabber IDs using the XMPP service, by bouncing messages to the users via your bot. You could also have a long-polling webpage to do it, but it would not be recommended. I strongly suggest you do a little more research about the platforms you intend to use before asking questions on Stack Overflow and expecting others to design your project for you.

Comment: @jason:thanks for ur replies.Actaully i dont have much experince in programming.Am just a collge passsout and passionate abt techology and starting my own website.So i ask questions over here.

Comment: @jason: can  please answer my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513287/running-my-own-jabber-xmpp-server

Comment: @jason: can u give me a good referance website for jabber/xmpp