# running my own jabber/xmpp server

Tags: chat, xmpp

1. Can I make my own jabber server.So
   that if I run my website *xyz* then
   people should be be able to get
   their jabber id from my website by
   registering on my website.
2. Is there any open source
   implementation of jabber server that
   I can use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) to run my Jabber server and am quite happy with it.  Probably higher-overhead than some of the other options (jabberd, ejabberd, etc.), but it's easy to install and has a great web-based admin UI.

As far as adding users via a web application - I don't know how you would go about doing that with Openfire, but it should be possible.  It can plug in to many databases, and you might be able to give your web application an admin account that it can use to create users.

Alternatively, the Jabber/XMPP protocol supports creating a new account when you first connect to a server, if that's good enough for you.  OpenFire supports that feature (as do most Jabber servers, I believe).

**Update:**  The [User Service Plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html) for Openfire exposes an HTTP API for performing user administration actions.  That's probably exactly what you need.

Comment: So if I use the User Service Plugin, then I can allow my user to create an account within my Android app, such as input a username, password and other related information? How is the back-end database configured?

Comment: @Sauron Yes, it looks like you can use the plugin to enable that functionality. I haven't used it myself, though, so I do not know the details. However, for just creating an account from an Android app, you may also be able to use XMPP's built-in account registration facilities. Back-end database configuration is an internal part of Openfire; consult the Openfire documentation for details.

Comment: I presently have a running android chat app using MySQL, Apache and  websockets. I have the fear of staying with websockets as the messages may be dropped as well as battery life drained. I was thinking of using PubNub to power the movement of messages, but have no basis of comparison. How do you feel about PubNub in building a chat app instead of simply XMPP in Android?

Comment: @Sauron Having never programmed for PubNub, Websockets, or XMPP (only administered a small XMPP server), I do not have opinions on that subject.

Answer (score 4):

> Can i make my own jabber server.So
>   that if i run my website xyz then
>   people should be be able to get theri
>   jabber id from my website by
>   registering on my website.

It depends on what kind of hosting you have. I think you should at least have [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) hosting to install the software. Basic hosting for a couple of bucks does not allow you to run jabber server.

```
Is there any open source implementation of jabber server that i can use?
```

I myself really like lua's [prosody](http://prosody.im/). It is easy to install / configure

Comment: +1 Prosody. Easy to setup. I have running on my Raspberry Pi, there's an arm package in the rpi apt-get repos. Uses about ~4MB memory according to `htop`.

Answer (score 3):

You might like ejabberd, it is fairly friendly to new users:

http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/

Comment: @mvid:thanks for replying.Can u please tell me is there any open source javascrip jabber client

Comment: There are many clients available, including pidgin for windows/linux or adium for osx

Answer (score 1):

For you first question:
You might want to look at the XEP-0077 extension for in-band registration.
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html#intro

What language are you coding in? You might want to check and see if that language has a XMPP library that can handle this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried most of them and can agree on ejabberd.  The only problem is that in order to change it, you need to program in Erlang.  Openfire looks great, but I could not get the certificate to load properly: there is a bug with the implementation, so TLS will not work.  I couldn't get Soapbox to access a local MySQL database, so that was out too.

As for client-side, you can use Miranda.